# Login via github hangs if accessed by domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, oauth, github-api

I have an app where a user can login using github. When I log in, the app hangs for about one minute. This is the log

```
Started GET "/" for 177.97.171.165 at 2013-08-11 15:26:01 +0000
Started GET "/sessions/new" for 177.97.171.165 at 2013-08-11 15:26:03 +0000
Started GET "/auth/github" for 177.97.171.165 at 2013-08-11 15:27:03 +0000
(github) Request phase initiated.
Started GET "/auth/github/callback?code=ade18bb431c9303c6274&state=deaf138aff766c6ec3480a54897ae8bbbe734e0dfe11790d" for 177.97.171.165 at 2013-08-11 15:27:05 +0000
(github) Callback phase initiated.
Started GET "/" for 177.97.171.165 at 2013-08-11 15:28:06 +0000
```

In the last line, I was successfully logged in. If I access the app using the IP instead of the domain, this doesn't happen. Has anyone seen something like this?

I'm using nginx 1.4.1, deploying with [dokku](https://github.com/progrium/dokku?source=c).

Comment: What does happen if you use the IP rather than the domain?

Comment: the login does not hangs for one minute.